# How to extract data using SAP Data Services from a HANA calculated view with input parameters, receiving error

Tags: hana

I am trying to extract data from a HANA calculated view. When I try to run the extract I receive an error message that the SQL statement is incorrect. If I try to update the schema in the SQL transform I receive the following error:

> ODBC Data source  error message for operation OdbcDB::describeQuery: [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 SQ syntax error ; incorrect syntax near "{": Line 4 col 42 (at pos 148)>. BODI-1130199

Here is the syntax I am using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "_AccessHANA"."HANA.HANA.app-tal-ana.app-hcm/CV_RPT_BIG_METRICS_VIEW"
     ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$IP_STARTFYPERIOD$',{$G_FY2015B})
     ,'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$IP_ENDFYPERIOD$', {$G_FY2015E}))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated with why this is not working when passing in the required parameters. I can provide screenshots if needed.

Thanks,

Nelson

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an SAP Data Services instance ready to test this, but I think it should work when the parameter placeholders for DS (the stuff in the curly brackets `{ ... }`) is between to single quotation marks `' ... '`.

Something like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "_AccessHANA"."HANA.HANA.app-tal-ana.app-hcm/CV_RPT_BIG_METRICS_VIEW"
     ('PLACEHOLDER' = ('$IP_STARTFYPERIOD$','{$G_FY2015B}')
     ,'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$IP_ENDFYPERIOD$', '{$G_FY2015E}'))
```

Also, you may want to consider using the new parameter syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM "_AccessHANA"."HANA.HANA.app-tal-ana.app-hcm/CV_RPT_BIG_METRICS_VIEW"
     (PLACEHOLDER."$IP_STARTFYPERIOD$" => '{$G_FY2015B}'
     ,PLACEHOLDER."$IP_ENDFYPERIOD$"   => '{$G_FY2015E}'))
```